# Git update without project folder

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-pull, git-clone

I have setup a repository in Github. I have used `SSH` protocol to establish connection to that repo in my web hosting. Then I have cloned the repo without the project folder like this.

```
git clone git@github.com:{username}/{git-name} .
```

All works without any problem.

Now, I want to use that repo as the final copy of my website i.e. every time I update the repo, my website will also be updated. So, I created a PHP script which contains

```
`git pull`
```

I put the script link as web hook url in Github settings. But nothing happens when I update my repo.

I don't understand what's the problem. Is it because I have cloned the site without repository folder?

Another problem is that, the `.git` folder is present inside the main website which means everyone can access that. Is there any solution to that?

I am pretty much new to Git and Github. So, detailed instruction will be very helpful. I am using Shared hosting with SSH shell access.

Comment: `git pull` is a `git fetch` + `git rebase` - it doesn't work inside bare repo. Do only `git fetch` part in your script.

Comment: @abyss.7 What can I do in this case. I can't have the repo folder as it defeats the primary goal.

Comment: Try to do `git fetch origin`, as I suggest in the first comment.

Comment: @abyss.7 It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't told git which branch you want to pull. So `git pull <your-branch>` should fix that problem.

With a .htaccess file within the .git folder you can refuse access to it:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
```

Comment: I am not looking for this solution. Something that would help me to put my git in a level up or something like that.